# how to Get a high output every third high input

Tags: digital-logic

I'm trying to get a logic circuit that will input high after 3 high inputs from a single source. I have tried using flip flops but the system activates closer to every 2nd input instead of every 3rd. could it be that im not using enough flip flops in the circuit ?

also it stays high for longer than i would like. could I please get some advice on how to fix these issues ?

Comment: Please describe exactly (schematic) what you've tried with flipflops. This is a state-machine-problem, and you'll need these, so that sounds like the right way to go. However, we can't comment on your approach without seeing your approach!

Comment: Maybe something like a CD4017 ic?

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here, so you will need to show us **all of the work** you have done so far. Then you should ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Insufficient specs. Define latency and pulse duration with clock f or use T=1/f. e.g. Do you want T pulse out /3 or T/2 or ?

Comment: @Euan Thoirs - the comment re homework is in fact a site requirement. The aim is t help people to learn and not to just provide answers. We are happy to help with homework but just providing answers dies not help people at exam time.  (I'm a site moderator).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with 1T every 3T clock edges and/ or T/2 every 3 Clk edges.

[here’s one way.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKDASWZXGO7ABZ+PblUhsOIXELC9JCPrNEsA7pMjSMhNdMUrtIFCiFT9Y1VwNHwYbibPXb6-Xb0WZfG+BR4oe-nC8ffyp3X3NPGx80H0iwg3xA+JjCJVVoxODEsQAlB0shfiirCD5KaBLoJBRKqChKlgBZEEzQ-kIdEQN69mwk8E19MAGqbiQEcV7MzG5+Yi1p2s7x1Sm8H2x5Uz0Nx2MnFybZ+YxR7wMTxfqAe2tJTv5mWjr4SDJCBEIUJBHb7BYbzzYe6PagwF5vD5fWqsAHkIHQlLoUGwOAQEIsIA)

Answer (score -1):

To do this you need to be able to count to 3, in binary of course.  In binary the number 3 is 11.  So you need 2 bits to count that which translates into 2 flip-flops.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFwdvS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Shouldn’t the output of the first flip flop feed into the clock of the second flip flop?  I didn’t down vote by the way.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  My bad!  I have corrected the schematic.  You can feed it to the clock but that can lead to unintended transition outputs from the AND gate.